# Adding a prefix div to Emails HTML body

Tags: python, html, gmail, mime-types, prefix

We're trying to add a warning to every email we find suspicious, but once we do that - not all emails are showing as expected after the change: - on some EMails we ruin the styling and the message is displayed differently, while on others we see the warning at the top of the email (similar to Google warnings). 
Are there any best practices for this action of adding a 'prefix' warning on the HTML part of the email? Do's/Don'ts ? Anything would be helpful! 

Here's a snippet:

```
def replace_body(self, email_instance, message_id, **kwargs):
    def _generate_html_part_from_plain(_part):
        _plain_text_body = _part.get_payload(decode=True)
        _content_charset = _part.get_content_charset()
        _artificial_html_body = '<div dir="ltr">{}</div>'.format(_plain_text_body.replace('\r\n', '<br>'))
        _html_part = MIMEText(_artificial_html_body, 'html', _content_charset)
        return _content_charset, _html_part

    body_prefix = self.generate_prefix(message_id, email_instance, kwargs)

    if not body_prefix:
        log('prefix is empty, no need to update body (message={message_id})')
        return True

    if email_instance.is_multipart():
        payload = email_instance.get_payload()
        for part in payload:
            if part.get_content_subtype() == 'html':
                self.log.debug('email is \'multipart\' - attaching HTML part with warning (message={})'
                               .format(message_id))
                prefixed_part = self.attach_email_prefix(body_prefix, part, 'html', part.get_content_charset())
                payload.remove(part)
                payload.append(prefixed_part)
                break
        # when no html part present
        else:
            for part in payload:
                if part.get_content_subtype() == 'plain':
                    self.log.debug('email is \'multipart\', but no \'html\' part found: '
                                   'generating and attaching HTML part with warning (message={})'
                                   .format(message_id))
                    content_charset, html_part = _generate_html_part_from_plain(part)
                    prefixed_part = self.attach_email_prefix(body_prefix, html_part, 'html', content_charset)
                    top_content_subtype = email_instance.get_content_subtype()
                    if top_content_subtype != 'alternative':
                        self.log.debug('email\'s top-content-subtype is {}, generating alternative part to hold'
                                       '\'plain\' and \'html\' parts, and attaching to email (message={})'
                                       .format(top_content_subtype, message_id))
                        alternative_part = MIMEMultipart('alternative')
                        new_plain_part = MIMEText(part.get_payload(decode=True), 'plain', content_charset)
                        alternative_part.set_payload([new_plain_part, prefixed_part])
                        payload.remove(part)
                        payload.append(alternative_part)
                    else:
                        payload.append(prefixed_part)
                    break

        email_instance.set_payload(payload)
    elif email_instance.get_content_subtype() == 'plain':
        self.log.debug('email is \'text/plain\', attaching artificial HTML part with warning (message={})'
                       .format(message_id))
        # plain_part = deepcopy(email_instance)
        content_charset, html_part = _generate_html_part_from_plain(email_instance)
        prefixed_part = self.attach_email_prefix(body_prefix, html_part, 'html', content_charset)
        email_instance.replace_header('Content-Type', 'multipart/alternative')
        new_plain_part = MIMEText(email_instance.get_payload(decode=True), 'plain', content_charset)
        email_instance.set_payload([new_plain_part, prefixed_part])
        # email_instance.attach(html_part)
    else:
        self.log.warning('failed to attach HTML warning (message={}, top-content-type={})'
                         .format(message_id, email_instance.get_content_type()))

    log('prefix attached to message successfully (message={message_id})')
    return True

def attach_email_prefix(self, prefix, email_instance, subtype='html', charset='us-ascii'):
    def attach_to_text(_part):
        sep = {'html': '<br>', 'text': '\r\n'}
        _part_payload = _part.get_payload(decode=True)
        if not isinstance(_part_payload, str):
            self.log.debug(
                'skipping prefix attaching: Content payload\'s type is not str: {}'.format(_part_payload))
            return _part
        _part.set_payload('{}{}{}'.format(prefix, sep[subtype], _part_payload), charset)
        return _part

    if email_instance.get_content_subtype() == subtype:
        return attach_to_text(email_instance)
```